# Can't create digital ocean droplet by vagrant

Tags: vagrant, digital-ocean

To use digital ocean as a vagrant provider, I followed instruction [here](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-digitalocean/).
But I get this error.

```
$ vagrant up --provider=degital_ocean
The provider 'degital_ocean' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.
```

This is a result of `$ vagrant plugin list`

```
sahara (0.0.16)
vagrant-berkshelf (1.3.7)
vagrant-digitalocean (0.5.3)
vagrant-hostsupdater (0.0.11)
vagrant-omnibus (1.2.1)
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled "digital". `$ vagrant up --provider=digital_ocean`